# Laravel installation on linux server which is already running plain PHP sites

Tags: php, laravel

I am a PHP developer with experience of few years and now I have a project that is going to be on Laravel framework. I have a very strange and very stupid question sorry for my language. I don't know why this question comes to my mind and I am not getting any satisfactory answer for it from google. My question is if I will install Laravel framework on my Linux server will it affect the plain PHP sites (without any framework) that are live on server or will they work smoothly and Laravel will not affect them at all?

I apologise I know my question is very stupid but I need its answer please help me.

Thank You.

Comment: Not if you do it correctly, with its own vhost pointing to the Laravel site

Comment: Laravel is an extension to PHP and not any sort of replacement.

Comment: Ok thanks so much both of you for your quick answers. :)